# Is there a way to tell if a certain element of a list exists?

Tags: python

I am trying to tell if a certain item of a list exists. Ie, I have a list with x elements, and I need to see if there is a list[5]. I know you can check to see if and where a list contains a certain item, but not if a certain element exists at all.

```
#example:
list=[0,0,0,0,0]
#bogus code, this is where I need help
if list[6].exists():
     print("It works")
else:
     print("Guys I really need help this one issue is all of my problems")
```

Comment: `if len(list) > 6`?

Comment: `if 0 <= 6 < len(list)`, then `list[6]` exists. Also, don't use `list` to name a list variable, as you're overwriting the class name.

Comment: What you want if element exists in list?

Comment: Consider whether a list is the right data structure to use if you depend on a specific number of elements existing.

Comment: Do you actually mean to ask whether or not the `list` contains the element `6`, and not whether `list` has a sixth element?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if `lst[i]` exists, check that `i < len(lst)` is true.

Or, just *assume* it exists, and catch the `IndexError` that is raised if it doesn't.

```
try:
    y = lst[i]
except IndexError:
    ...
```

The first technique is faster if you think the test will fail often; the second technique is faster if you think the test will usually pass.

Answer (score 1):

You can check length of list:

```
checked_index = 6
if checked_index < len(list):
    print('Ok')
else:
    print(':(')
```

---

maybe you need some additional logic, for example, check that `checked_index` can't be negative or so on - it easily to modify `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can do it by following way.

```
#example:
lst=[0,0,0,0,0]
#bogus code, this is where I need help
if len(lst) > 5:
     print("It works")
else:
     print("Your problem got solved.")
```